# 802.11 Protocol on Different Frequency

Tags: protocol-theory, ieee-802.11, network-theory

Wifi (and the 802.11 protocol) takes place on 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz frequencies. Is it possible to recreate this protocol on a different frequency (say 500Mhz) and create a functional network using a modded AP and WiFi card on a device? If so, how could this be done?

Comment: You can invent any protocol you want. But 802.11 specifies modulation methods that may not work at such low frequencies. I doubt you could modify existing hardware. Then there are also licensing issues if you’re using different frequencies.

Comment: Technically, yes. But the fact you're asking the question, I doubt you're capable of making the mods, or have the qualifications to legally do so. (In the US, the FCC would fine you heavily for doing this. Plus, the illegal use of a licensed frequency.) I've seen commercial products using 802.11 over 900MHz, and 3.5/3.6GHz; they're intended for WISP markets **and require licensing**

Answer (score 1):

> Wifi (and the 802.11 protocol) takes place on 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz
> frequencies.

Not just those. Foe example, there is also a variant at 60 GHz. The restriction of frequencies is a regulatory one. Governments regulate the airwaves, and determine what frequencies are for what use. Using a regulated frequency for something other than what is allowed can get you in deep trouble.

> Is it possible to recreate this protocol on a different frequency (say
> 500Mhz) and create a functional network using a modded AP and WiFi
> card on a device? If so, how could this be done?

You need radios for different frequencies. For example, devices that can use either 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz have two different radios. As I explained above, IEEE 802.11 is not tied to any particular frequency, except by law.

Comment: The subsections do specify the PHY layer, so they do include the frequencies.

Comment: Different countries use different frequencies because they have different regulations. You must match the equipment to the country.